# Calculation Error or?

Tags: arithmetic

[image]

Is it a calculation error or am I missing something? A popular company like Plimus that handles thousands of payments daily can't make this mistake, I thought.

Comment: Yes, it's a calculation error (or, more likely, a typo), about on the same level as ending your question with "everymade can't make".

Comment: Ha! :) I did correct it but it somehow used the older version after I logged in.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue? I don't think there's much else that an answer could contain than what you said in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a calculation error, or, more likely, a typo; if you change the number of orders to 100, then everything works out.

What worries me is that on a \$49.90 transaction, there's a commission of \$4.99, while on a \$50 transaction, the commission drops to \$4.50. So, if the transaction is \$49.90, it pays you to lie and report it as \$50, and come out of the deal 49 cents better. Similarly at all the other percentage breakpoints.